# XAML browser window -- Tab navigation not working for loaded webpage

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a C# application and at one point open a browser designed in XAML but the tab navigation (Tabbing from username to password, hitting enter after entering password to trigger submit) is not working.

This previously was working and as far as I know I had not changed anything for that file.

In this window I can type in the username and password without issue so regular key presses are going through just fine. Does anyone know how I broke this and how to fix it?

Edit: with code now

```
<Window x:Class="ExternalFileManager.BrowserWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Sign In" Height="560" Width="530">
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser Height="520" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="webBrowser" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="505" LoadCompleted="webBrowser_LoadCompleted" />
</Grid>
</Window>

public BrowserWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        webBrowser.Navigate(signInUrl);
    }

private void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //Commented out for testing this problem
    }
```

This is how it's called

```
private void btn_logIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.responseData = null;
        BrowserWindow browser = new BrowserWindow();
        browser.Closed += new EventHandler(browser_Closed);
        browser.Show();
    }
```

Comment: We can't really tell unless you post some code ...

Comment: What are we supposed to guess from this ? Obviously what you've posted works, your error is somewhere else.

Comment: @Aybe I've added all relevant code, nothing else would interact with it. I commented out the code in webBrowser_LoadCompleted for debugging earlier but that didn't change anything. Where else could my error be? I don't know where else to look.